# is it possible use react-speech-recognition without using react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, speech-recognition

I have copied an open-source web game with canvas written with javascript and I want to implement the "react-speech-recognition" API(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition)

to use this API I need to create a react app which renders HTML. Is it possible to create a simple class with react that I can import and use it in my javascript code?

this is the code in react:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import SpeechRecognition from "react-speech-recognition";

const propTypes = {
  // Props injected by SpeechRecognition
  transcript: PropTypes.string,
  resetTranscript: PropTypes.func,
  browserSupportsSpeechRecognition: PropTypes.bool
};

const Dictaphone = ({
  transcript,
  resetTranscript,
  browserSupportsSpeechRecognition
}) => {
  if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
      <span>{transcript}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

Dictaphone.propTypes = propTypes;

export default SpeechRecognition(Dictaphone);
```

how can I use that sample code and create a class with simple methods to call them?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked in the description of `react-speech-recognition` is a reference to [SpeechRecognition API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) that includes some examples. Copied from there:

```
var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar colors; public <color> = aqua | azure | beige | bisque | black | blue | brown | chocolate | coral | crimson | cyan | fuchsia | ghostwhite | gold | goldenrod | gray | green | indigo | ivory | khaki | lavender | lime | linen | magenta | maroon | moccasin | navy | olive | orange | orchid | peru | pink | plum | purple | red | salmon | sienna | silver | snow | tan | teal | thistle | tomato | turquoise | violet | white | yellow ;'
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
var speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
//recognition.continuous = false;
recognition.lang = 'en-US';
recognition.interimResults = false;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;

var diagnostic = document.querySelector('.output');
var bg = document.querySelector('html');

document.body.onclick = function() {
  recognition.start();
  console.log('Ready to receive a color command.');
}

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  var color = event.results[0][0].transcript;
  diagnostic.textContent = 'Result received: ' + color;
  bg.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

A good practice to get into is to check what browsers will support your code - [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition) is a great resource for this.